# how to post the database value to next page using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am trying to post the database retrieved value to next page using ajax.i tried but it not posting, can any one guide me how to do it

php

connected with database

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `billingdatainputandexport` WHERE id='1'"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
//print $sql;
 $billingmonth=$rows['billingmonth'];
```

i want to pass this billing month to selectsuppliercostprice.php.

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#supplier").on("change", function() {

        var billingmonth='$billingmonth';
        var supplier = document.getElementById("supplier").value;
        var mcc = document.getElementById("mcc").value;
        var mnc = document.getElementById("mnc").value;
        $.post('selectsuppliercostprice.php', { org: supplier,mcc: mcc,mnc: mnc,billingmonth: billingmonth }, function(result) {
            $('#suppliercost').html(result);
            }
        );
    });
});
```

**selectsuppliercostprice.php.**

```
   $billingmonth=$_POST['billingmonth'];
```

Comment: It's `$_POST`, not `$POST`

Comment: @arok How you're retrieving `billingmonth` value to jQuery function?

Comment: thanks for your reply i tried but still not posting

Comment: like this am right var billingmonth='$billingmonth';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this,

**PHP**

```
$billingmonth=$rows['billingmonth'];

echo '<input type="hidden" id="billingmonth" name="billingmonth" value="'.$billingmonth.'">'; // added hidden input
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#supplier").on("change", function() {
    var billingmonth= $('#billingmonth').val();
    ...
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

The post variable is $_POST not $POST so ... that should be right:

```
$billingmonth = $_POST['billingmonth'];
```

Also in Javascript you have to print the billingmonth variable. Javascript can't handle php-variables:

```
var billingmonth='$billingmonth';
```

to

```
var billingmonth='<?php echo $billingmonth; ?>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the latest code : u missed i guess the php tag inside ur script tag now try :)

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#supplier").on("change", function() {

            var billingmonth='<?php echo $billingmonth ?>';
            var supplier = document.getElementById("supplier").value;
            var mcc = document.getElementById("mcc").value;
            var mnc = document.getElementById("mnc").value;
            $.post('selectsuppliercostprice.php', { org: supplier,mcc: mcc,mnc: mnc,billingmonth: billingmonth }, function(result) {
                $('#suppliercost').html(result);
                }
            );
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

make hidden field and store your value in that and read that value in javascaript and pass it with ajax

```
        <input type="hidden" name="some_name" value="<?php echo $billingmonth?>" id="some_name"/>
```

javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#supplier").on("change", function() {

        var billingmonth=document.getElementById('billingmonth').value;
        var supplier = document.getElementById("supplier").value;
        var mcc = document.getElementById("mcc").value;
        var mnc = document.getElementById("mnc").value;
        $.post('selectsuppliercostprice.php', { org: supplier,mcc: mcc,mnc: mnc,billingmonth: billingmonth }, function(result) {
            $('#suppliercost').html(result);
            }
        );
    });
});
```

if you don't want to use it anyother place than

```
   var billingmonth= '<?php echo $billingmonth?>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Try.

Store `$billingmonth` value into any hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" name="billing_month" id="billing_month" value="<?php echo $billingmonth; ?>"/>
```

Retrieve $billingmonth value in jQuery ready function using Hidden input id.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#supplier").on("change", function() {

        var billingmonth=$("#billing_month").val();
        var supplier = $("#supplier").val();
        var mcc = $("#mcc").val();
        var mnc =$("#mnc").val();
        $.post('selectsuppliercostprice.php', { org: supplier,mcc: mcc,mnc: mnc,billingmonth: billingmonth }, function(result) {
            $('#suppliercost').html(result);
            }
        );
    });
});
```